# method call works only after event

Tags: ios, xcode

My problem is this: I have the following method as part of a custom framework. When I call the method after an event (e.g. IBAction or textFieldShouldReturn) the method gets called. But if I just call it through code e.g.

> [_someView show];

the method does not get called. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
- (void) show {
    if (!_shouldShow) {
        //show
        self.hidden = FALSE;
        if (_descriptionDefaultVisible) {
            descriptionShowing = TRUE;
        }
        _shouldShow = TRUE;
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self positionSubviews];

    if (!didPositionSubviesInside) {
        [self positionSubviewsInside];
        didPositionSubviesInside = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `_someView` non nil and valid =when it fails?

Comment: have you instantiated that particular view before you call a method on it?

Comment: Definitely need more info. But the only thing I see is that, this - `_shouldShow` - might be set/used also by the framework. Hence the method did get called, but the `if` is not entered when you called it yourself. But the framework, let say, might change it to `FALSE` before it calls it. Dunno, just guessing, given only what you have shown.

Comment: Yes, I call the "show" method after the view's initialisation.

Comment: What I am saying is perhaps: `_shouldShow` and `didPositionSubviesInside` is set by the framework that you are using to `TRUE` initially.

Comment: Actually, you are partly right, the method IS getting called but also it runs through the if .The first property is FALSE by default. But the view does not appear (as should happen after self.hidden = FALSE;)

Comment: Views are not necessarily fully instantiated at `viewDidLoad` but are at `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing in the name of your view to scope the method you type [self methodName].  This should allow you to reference the show method inside of another method (assuming it is inside the same .m file as the show method).

Comment: They are in different files. The "show" method is part of the framework.